# AWS user-uploaded file hosting from EC2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

I have an Web App that requires user-uploaded file hosting (~ 10-200mb each file). In my local-environment, I have been hosting these files in a separate folder. That said, I need to somehow do the same from the EC2 environment. I thought AWS' S3 would fulfill my need but it seems like I cannot send files there as it if was a separate folder from my EC2 instance.

Any recommendations for CDN-type hosting on AWS?

Comment: To clarify: Do you want to host a webapp on EC2 that allows users to upload large files? You're uncertain as to the best way to store these files?

Comment: AWS S3 is the correct place to store these files. You'll just need to become familiar with the S3 API's for your chosen language.

Answer (score 0):

AWS S3 is a good choice for a scalable object store that's accessible from EC2.

S3 clients are available in a [variety of languages](https://aws.amazon.com/tools/).

For providing client uploads, you might want to check out [presigned urls](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/PresignedUrlUploadObject.html). These can be used to give your users a convienient URL that they can POST their data to.

Answer (score 0):

If you plan to upload files with minimal change to the web app code, you can consider using Amazon Elastic File System (EFS). It works in a way that you can mount EFS to a folder of your EC2 instance (Also possible to mount the same file system to another EC2 instance if your web app scales out). After mounting its more similar to writing to the file system. Another advantage you get with this approach is that you will get infinite storage with EFS and you will pay for the storage consumption. You will also get regional replication for higher durability of data.

However, you can also consider S3 your n the long run, if you plan to upload and serve the content through a CDN and if you are not doing frequent modifications to the uploaded files. The advantage of this over EFS comes with serverless benefits where you don’t need to run a web server to serve these files over http or through a CDN, life cycle policies, inbuilt security models, native support for event driven workflows with S3 triggers and etc.